# How to support both short and long options at the same time in bash?

Tags: bash, getopt, getopt-long

I want to support both short and  long options in `bash` scripts, so one can:

```
$ foo -ax --long-key val -b -y SOME FILE NAMES
```

is it possible?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Comment: Although the nominated duplicate is asking specifically about `getopts`, there are several answers which suggest different approaches.  I agree with the close.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`getopt` supports long options.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html

Here is an example using your arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS=`getopt -o axby -l long-key: -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "Got a"; shift;;
        -b) echo "Got b"; shift;;
        -x) echo "Got x"; shift;;
        -y) echo "Got y"; shift;;
        --long-key) echo "Got long-key, arg: $2"; shift 2;;
        --) shift; break;;
    esac
done
echo "Args:"
for arg
do
    echo $arg
done
```

Output of `$ foo -ax --long-key val -b -y SOME FILE NAMES`:

```
Got a
Got x
Got long-key, arg: val
Got b
Got y
Args:
SOME
FILE
NAMES
```

Comment: Some versions of `getopt` have problems with some characters in arguments and and non-option parameters. If `getopt --test; echo $?` outputs "4", you're OK. If it outputs "0" you have a version with this problem. See [`man getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) for more information.

Comment: And also POSIXLY_CORRECT environment is useful.

Comment: Xiè Jìléi: Why? How do you set that?

Comment: By the way, the link no longer works. Here is a replacement on Archive.Org [https://web.archive.org/web/20090130140546/http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getopt.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20090130140546/http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_getopt.htm)