# Including sub-parameters in help options to execute wisely?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am writing a script which can choose a file and print specific content. For example,

```
san#./script.sh

Expected Usage : ./script.sh --file1 --dns
```

(Here it checks for file1, search for dns name and prints. Basically there are sub-parameters under a parameter)

I tried for single parameter/Option as below :

```
options=$@

arguments=($options)

index=0;
for argument in $options
do
    index=`expr $index + 1`;
    case $argument in
    -a | --fun1 ) run_function1 ;;
    -b | --fun2 ) run_function2 ;;
    -c | --fun3 ) run_function3 ;;
    esac
done
exit;

[ ${1} ] || helpinfo
```

Can any one suggest for double parameter(sub options) ?

Expected target options :

```
./script.sh


OPTIONS : ./script.sh -h

./script --fun1 stackoverflow
        microsoft
        Google
     --fun2 Yahoo
```

Basically each function will look into one file. I have looked into getopt or getopts, But it doesn't have long option (`--long` is not possible, instead we can use only `-l`). But again not sure of sub parameters. Can any one help on this ?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180880/how-to-support-both-short-and-long-options-at-the-same-time-in-bash

Comment: It's not I am mainly looking for sub options. not just short/long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you properly ... but let's try my luck :)

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

function fun1 {
   echo "fun1 '$1'"
}

function fun2 {
   echo "fun2 '$1'"
}

function err {
   echo "No function has been specified"
   exit 1
}

FUNCTION=err
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
   case "$1" in
      -a | --fun1 ) FUNCTION=fun1 ;;
      -b | --fun2 ) FUNCTION=fun2 ;;
      *) $FUNCTION "$1" ;;
   esac
   shift
done

$ ./a.sh --fun1 one two -b three
fun1 'one'
fun1 'two'
fun2 'three'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed FAQ dealing with parameter parsing (including what you call "suboptions"): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: I don't find much details to implement in my scenario. Can you give me a sample code from the above details ? Thanks!